# There's some blurry text I cant quite read, any ideas what it is/means?

Tags: meaning

準繫詞語 is my best guess as to what it says, what does this mean? I know it's some kind of word class description, but these jerks wrote it in 繁体字 in the smallest font possible... ( and/or Im an idiot)

Any ideas guys?

Here:

[image]

Comment: Not nice calling them "jerks". Anyone with a bit of habit (apparently including you!) can read 繫.

Comment: Sorry, I was just playing around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it says 準繫詞語 (准系词语), and according to [Chinese Wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B3%BB%E8%A9%9E), this means **pseudo-copula**.

Comment: Thanks !!! 

In case anyone looks at this in the future I've discovered a pseudo copula is a fancy linguistic term that means:  a word that links a subject in a sentence with a predicate. But a seMI copula is a linking verb that is less commonly used e.g. the dog IS sick is a main copula and the dog SEEMS sick is a semi copula. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)

Comment: @3龙花 No worries. Though did you mean to say a *copula* is a word that links the subject and the predicate, whereas a *pseudo-copula* is what you stated above that’s also known as a *semi-copula*?